# Issue with actionListener/actionhandler java NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, actionlistener

My issue is that when trying to excute my code, I keep getting NullPointerException on my actionListener. Here is my login view. Exception occurs in the LoginView class after some testing.

```
public class LoginView extends JDialog {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField tfUsername;
private JPasswordField pfPassword;
private JLabel lbUsername;
private JLabel lbPassword;
private JButton btnLogin;
private JButton btnCancel;
private boolean succeeded;

/*public LoginView(Frame parent) {

    super(parent, "Login", true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
}*/

public void createUI(){

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints cs = new GridBagConstraints();

    cs.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

    lbUsername = new JLabel("Username: ");
    cs.gridx = 0;
    cs.gridy = 0;
    cs.gridwidth = 1;
    panel.add(lbUsername, cs);

    tfUsername = new JTextField(20);
    cs.gridx = 1;
    cs.gridy = 0;
    cs.gridwidth = 2;
    panel.add(tfUsername, cs);

    lbPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
    cs.gridx = 0;
    cs.gridy = 1;
    cs.gridwidth = 1;
    panel.add(lbPassword, cs);

    pfPassword = new JPasswordField(20);
    cs.gridx = 1;
    cs.gridy = 1;
    cs.gridwidth = 2;
    panel.add(pfPassword, cs);
    panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));

    btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Login in button is pushed ");

        }

    });

    btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    /*btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
        }
    });*/
    JPanel bp = new JPanel();
    bp.add(btnLogin);
    bp.add(btnCancel);

    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(bp, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);



    pack();
    setResizable(false);


}

//action listener will be handle in LoginController
public void addLoginListener(ActionListener listenForLoginButton){

    btnLogin.addActionListener(listenForLoginButton); //error occurs here

}

public void addCancelListener(ActionListener listenForCancelButton){

    btnLogin.addActionListener(listenForCancelButton);// and here

}

//return user-name
public String getUsername() {
    return tfUsername.getText().trim();
}

//return password
public String getPassword() {
    return new String(pfPassword.getPassword());
}

public boolean isSucceeded() {
    return succeeded;
}
}
```

Here is tha controller and its inner class that is the action handler

```
/*The LoginController class handles the logic behind login validation and and 
 * error handling connected to login*/
public class LoginController{
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private DatabaseConnection databaseConnection; //not using yet
private LoginView loginView;


/*the constructor two parameters databaseConnection and loginView
 * true to are MVC frameworke*/ 
public LoginController(DatabaseConnection databaseConnection, LoginView loginView){

    this.databaseConnection = databaseConnection;
    this.loginView = loginView;



    this.loginView.addLoginListener(new LoginHandler());
    this.loginView.addCancelListener(new LoginHandler());
}

public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    /* hard-coded user-name and password, because we know what the 
     * user-name and password is*/

    if (username.equals("bob") && password.equals("secret")) {

        return true;

    }

    return false;
}



/***********************/
/*****Inner class*******/
/***********************/

class LoginHandler implements ActionListener{

    //an empty constructor
    public LoginHandler(){

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        //this switch will only handle 2 events, login is pushed or cancel is pushed
        switch(e.getActionCommand()){

        case "btnLogin":

            System.out.println("Login in button is pushed ");

            break;

        case "btnCancel":

            System.out.println("cancel in button is pushed ");

            break;


        }
    }
}

/***********************/
/****end inner class****/
/***********************/

}//end class
```

And the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at se.bbs.nackademin.views.LoginView.addLoginListener(LoginView.java:94)
at se.bbs.nackademin.controllers.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:30)
at se.bbs.nackademin.main.Demo.main(Demo.java:23)
```

Comment: The exception stack trace tells you exactly where the problem is. Don't neglect to read it, and post it if you can't understand it. It's crucial information. That's where you should start to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Moreover, why you changing what you getting with `getPassword()` to `String`. This is done for security reasons and you pushing your application to the abyss, from which the developers of Java are trying to bring one out. Moreover, write `btnLogin.addActionListener(LoginHandlerReferenceGoesHere)`, inside your `LoginView` class.

Comment: I'll second what @JBNizet said. Stacktraces are meant to aid the developer in isolating problems. Don't skip them! Please post stacktraces wherever possible. And, welcome to SO. :)

Comment: sry, just added the stacktrace

Comment: don't see where you call createGUI - maybe you forgot to call it at all? Then btnLogin/btnCancel would still be null ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace says that the exception happens at this line of the LoginController constructor:

```
this.loginView.addLoginListener(new LoginHandler());
```

What could possibly be null at this line? There is only one possibility: `this.loginView`.

This field has been initialized just before with the value of the `loginView` argument of the constructor.

```
this.loginView = loginView;
```

So it simply means that the caller of this constructor passes null instead of passing a `LoginView` instance.

Who is the caller of this constructor? The stack trace tells us: `se.bbs.nackademin.main.Demo.main(Demo.java:23)`

So, the bug is there. The main method of the class `Demo` passes null to the constructor of `LoginController`. The faulty code is at line 23 in `Demo.java`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, JB Nizet reolved my issue, in my Demo class i created an instance loginView but trigger the createUI method after passing loginView in to LoginController.